# Create Random Folder, copy to random folder

Tags: c#

Need Help creating Random Folder name and copying files to that folder. I have tried to use the following but it kills storescp once the folder is created. So I need the folder to be created and added to the string but I dont know how to store the name of the folder that was created by the random function.

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 1);
var Result = Path.GetRandomFileName();

var Name = Directory.CreateDirectory(dicompath +"\\"+ Result);
///////////////////////////////
finalpath = port + " -pm" + " --fork " + " -aet " + AE +" " + "-od " + ((char)34) + Name + ((char)34);
Process startInfo2 = new Process();
            startInfo2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo2.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo2.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\dcmtk\bin\storescp-tls.exe";
            startInfo2.StartInfo.Arguments = finalpath;
            startInfo2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            //int seconds = await SleepAsync(2000);
        startInfo2.Start();
```

Comment: [`CreateDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use `Name.FullName`.

Comment: Why not use a `Guid` ? You could simply do a `string randomName = new Guid().ToString();` and then use the variable `randomName` like this: `Directory.CreateDirectory(discompath + "\\" + randomName);` and store the path in a variable like so: `var path = discompath + "\\" + randomName;`

Comment: Kevin Jensen Peterson, that seems to work. thx you rock.

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how to make it public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a random number path (I've also tidied up your concatenation):

```
string dir = Path.Combine(dicompath, new Random().Next(0, 10));
Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
string final = string.Format("{0} -pm --fork -aet {1} -od \"{2}\"", port, AE, dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

best approach is to use [GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) as random name for your folder.

You can use it like this:

```
var randomName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString():
var fullPath = Path.Combine(dicompath, randomName);
Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
finalpath = port + " -pm" + " --fork " + " -aet " + AE +" " + "-od " + ((char)34) + fullPath + ((char)34);
//.... rest of your code....
```